# Ajax async call true return value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I need some help with ajax call, I have problem with async true. So I have form on html page and i am using ajax call to call me the php script that is sending the data to email and then it returns the value back to page and displays notification regarding the value returned. So far everything worked ok with this code:

```
$.validator.setDefaults( {
    submitHandler: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Link - script to send info and returns the value',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == '1') {
                    $("#error").hide();
                    $("#validate").hide();
                    $("#poslano").show();
                }else {
                    $("#error").show();
                }
            },
        });
    }
} );
```

So after all inputs are correct the form if submitted and this part of ajax script sends the data to script and get the returned value. But if I have async set to false I always get this error back even if form is correct:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

But if I set async to true, then nothing happens. I just get the error message. How should i resolve this problem ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a `console.log(result);` and check the value......

Comment: Don't you think that error message that you get will be helpful here?

Comment: Sorry I might put that in wrong words, I don't get any error that i can see back. Just my custom error is always triggered.

Comment: @Aljaz But the `result` still has some value, right? Check what `result` is. It ought to tell you what happened.

Comment: @Aljaz maybe `method` insead of `type`?

Comment: Thanks for help, how should I resolve the problem with result now? If I use async: true; which works, but then the browser doesn't freeze if I am correct to wait for result, how should I handle result in that case? Whit event?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.

Resolved

**async: false;**

changed to

**async: true;**

and now it works no more errors in console.

Thank you again.

But if I use async: true; then the browser doesn't freeze if I am correct to wait for result, how should I handle result in that case? Whit event?